# How to resolve a "max_allowed_packet" error when connecting PyCharm to a remote MySQL db via SSH?

Tags: mysql, pycharm

I want to be able to connect to and work with a MySQL database that I have on DigitalOcean via PyCharm's database interface (instead of MySQL Workbench, which is what I'm currently using), but when I try to use PyCharm's interface to connect, I get the following error when I click 'Test Connection':

`Packet for query is too large (###### > ######). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.`

I'm connecting to DigitalOcean via SSH, and PyCharm is saying that my SSH connection is OK (it's working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I was putting the wrong IP address and port into PyCharm's prompt: I was putting the IP address to my DigitalOcean VM instead of the local IP address of the MySQL db.

Here's a screenshot of the PyCharm settings that ended up working (remember, I was connecting via SSH):
[image]

Here's a screenshot of my (working) MySQL Workbench settings, showing which settings I should have copied over to PyCharm:
[image]